# Do I have to have LaunchScreen.xib for iOS 8 launch images?

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

I'm using Xcode 6.1.

In Launch Image sources = LaunchImage and in Launch Screen File = Main_iPhone. In Images.xcassets under Launch Image Name = LaunchImage.

I currently have a Retina HD 5.5 and Retina HD4.7 Launch Image in appropriate sizes for iOS 8. Yet for all iOS 8 devices whether on iPhone 4s, iPhone5's, or iPhone 6's, iOS 8 doesn't load Launch Image. I don't use xib, only storyboards. However, do I have to create an xib file called LaunchScreen.xib and put my iOS 8 Launch Images in that file for iOS 8 to launch the images?

So i'd put just 2 iOS 8 images in there and xib has no problem with me using storyboards to build game? Is that the only way for a Launch Image to work for iOS 8 in Xcode 6.1?

**edit:**
So I just made a LaunchScreen.xib file. In that file I put my Retina HD 4.7 inch launch image for the 4.7 inch screen. In Launch Screen File I put as LaunchScreen.xib I still get the same result. iOS 7 launch images load but iOS 8 launch images don't load.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but had marked the xib as a launch screen, but just needed to select it as the launch xib in the build settings, general tab.

[image: Build Settings]

Answer (score 1):

Have you marked the view in the xib as "Use as Launch Screen" in the File Inspector?

[image]

Comment: Hi, how did you het to that view

Comment: @TeodorKolev Select the XIB file for editing then on the far right pane, select the "File Inspector" (first icon, looks like the document icon). This info will be about halfway down the column.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed last checkbox, but I still see it as a  launch screen